# Opening File List: How to do it quicker?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form that returns a list of SQL files stored in a certain document to a ListView on the form. Once an item is selected from the list, the SQL file is then opened in MS SQL Server. The code works, but it's terribly slow at populating the list, even though I only have 16 files in the folder.

Initially it returned the file name, modified date, created date, size and path, but I cut it down to just name, modified and path in the hope it would speed the code up but no luck.

I also tried changing the GetFolder part to Dir but I had trouble getting it to work (I'm still fairly new to VBA so not 100% clued up on the ins and outs of it).

I would be grateful for any support you can give me in making the code more efficient/quicker to run. Thanks.

```
Sub populatelist()
Dim fso As Object
Dim fldr As Object
Dim Files As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim li As ListItem

With Excel.Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
         
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

If PackageAvailable("SQL") = True Then
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("P:\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\")
    Set Files = fldr.Files
         
    For Each oFile In Files
        Set li = frmSQL.lstQueries.ListItems.Add(, , oFile.Name)
        li.SubItems(1) = Format$(oFile.DateLastModified, "DD MMM YYYY")
        li.SubItems(2) = oFile.ParentFolder
    Next
End If
    
EndProc:

On Error Resume Next

Set li = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
Set fldr = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

With Excel.Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With
   
Exit Sub
   
ErrHandler:
   
MsgBox "ERROR: " & Err.Description, vbexclmation, "Error"
Resume EndProc
   
End Sub
```

---

#### Resolved

Changing the file path as Tom suggested worked. Bizarrely it's the same location but another path to get there but works fine.

Comment: Just as a side note, at this stage I'm not wanting to run the query from Excel; I just want Excel to open the file in SQL Server (as if you double clicked the file itself).

Comment: Why are you setting calculation to manual and then back to automatic here?

Comment: Copy and pasting error. I pasted the whole block in from another code trying to add things to make it run quicker. Will take it out.

Comment: Are you sure that there are only 16 files in that folder? Is P: your local drive?

Comment: Yes definitely only 16. There's a couple of empty folders I think; would that have any impact? It's under my documents, but I think it's stored on a network rather than locally. Is it worth moving the stuff to a local drive?

Comment: @Tom + 1. Changed the location and it all works. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

To give a broader answer to that question.

In general, vba loops are not always the best decision for solving problems in excel and the like. In comparison to bulk operations, loops will always be a bit slower. (Also see [here](https://www.soa.org/News-and-Publications/Newsletters/Compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42-roper.aspx))

If you HAVE to use loops, make sure that you are only looping through data that is worth it. Try to minimize your sample as much as you can e.g. with filters on data in excel or (as in OPs case) relocating of files. Most of the times your solution to a problem will be easier to write and be better in performance, if you really think about your data set first.

In general: the less, the better.

HTH